# Calculus: Determining function from the graph of its derivative

Tags: calculus

The figure(attached below) shows the graph of df/dx , the derivative of a twice differentiable function f , on the closed interval 0<= x <= 8. The graph of df/dx has horizontal tangent lines at x=1,x=3 , and x=5 . The function f is defined for all real numbers.

[image: Figure]

Answer the following questions.

1)On which open interval(s) contained in 0< x < 8 is the graph of f both concave down and decreasing (simultaneously)?(integer value)

2)The function g is defined by g(x) = (f(x))^3 . If f(3) = -5/2, find the slope of the line tangent to the graph of g at x=3 .

I don't know how to precede with them, please help.

Comment: Hint: if $f$ starts increasing when the blue curve passes through a root, then $f$ flips and is decreasing. So you have find the intervals where $f$ is increasing and decreasing, and try to find where in the intervals the function is concave down.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is decreasing if $f'(x) <0$

The function is concave down if $f''(x)<0$  Based on the graph how do you eyeball where $f''(x)<0$?

$g(x) = f^3(x)\\
g'(x) = 3f^2(x)f'(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Something of critical importance here is that you are not actually determining the graph of the function $f(x)$; while we are going to say some things about what it is doing, we at no point have to draw anything. In fact, except for the final step in your 2nd question, we won't even need to compute any specific values of $f(x)$ or $f'(x)$ at all.

For question 1, what is the definition of "decreasing" and "concave down"? Since our function is twice differentiable we can use the first and second derivative tests to characterize these two concepts. Decreasing means that the first derivative is negative, and concave down means that the 2nd derivative is negative. The big trick to stitching these two facts together will be that the first derivative $f'(x)$ must be decreasing when the second derivative $f''(x)$ is negative, since the second derivative of $f$ is just the derivative of the first derivative. (What a mouthful!)

For question 2, you are given a new function $g(x)=f(x)^3$ and asked to find the slope of the tangent line at $x=3$. Well, what is the slope of the tangent line? It's the value of the derivative of $g$ at that point. So take the derivative! You will have to use the chain rule to figure this one out, and at the end you will plug in $x=3$ everywhere. We have been told that $f(3)=\frac{-5}{2}$, and we can read off the value of $f'(3)$ from the picture you provided.

Hopefully this helps!